# Regenerate a .CSR file from .KEY and .PFX file?

Tags: .net, code-signing, pfx, csr, code-signing-certificate

I have a SHA-1 Code Signing Certificate issued from GoDaddy which expires soon.

I've requested a renewal, and re-keyed it from my current machine using the auto-key -- everything works, except when I sign my .NET assemblies with it, they get a different public key token than before!

I noticed that when I re-key via supplying a `.csr` -- as long as I re-supply the same `.csr` every time, the public key token does not change.

I've created my new `.csr`, and `.key` files using the following command (and then filling in the fields as appropriate):

```
openssl req -out companyname.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout companyname.key
```

(The old certificate was also created using the auto-browser method, but on a VM that's corrupt and can't be used any longer.  My understanding is that the auto-browser method basically generates the `.csr` and `.key` file for you and it's machine specific.)

For the old key that's not yet expired, I have a `.key` file that GoDaddy let me download, and a `.pfx` file that I generated myself using command line tools (I converted the key to a `.pvk` at one point, and merged that with the `.spc` file, etc.), and I know what values the CSR fields must have (as far as C, CN, O, etc.).

**My Question:**
Is there any way to derive what the old `.csr` file must have been (or a compatible / equivalent `.csr` file) from this data, such that I can re-key my certificate back to one that generates the same public key token as before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, looks like you can generate a new `.csr` file from the existing `.key` file pretty easily.  Then re-keying the certificate from this `.csr` allows you the generate a `.pfx` that will let you strong name assemblies with the same public key token that you had before.  Awesome.

The command to do it is:

```
openssl req -out companyname.csr -new -key companyname.key
```

It's that easy!